# Want to Create a Sorted Array From a Dictionary of objects with Links

Tags: objective-c, linked-list, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an **NSDictionary** of `MyModel` objects where each key is an **NSString** representing the `uid` property of the object. Each model has a property called `nextModel` which has the `uid` string of the model that should be sorted after the current one when displayed. It's basically a **virtual linked list**.

I'm trying to write a function that ***puts the models in order into an NSArray.**

I haven't found anything searching. **Anyone have any suggestions?**

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this that is very simple

```
NSArray *array = [dictionary.allValues sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"nextModel" ascending:YES]]];
```

If you want some more custom sorting, try a comparator.

```
NSArray *array = [dictionary.allValues sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if (obj1.value > obj2.value) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
}];
```

Comment: The nextModel is just a random alphanumeric string. So I don't think sorting it will work. It needs to be looked up

Comment: If you wanted to do custom sorted look at the second option. You could look up the ids there and compare as necessary entirely custom.